# How do I subset a 2D grid from another 2D grid in python?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have gridded data over the contiguous United States and I'm trying to select a chunk of it over a specific area.

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = '/Users/me/myfile.nc'
full_data = Dataset(filename,'r')
latitudes = full_data.variables['latitude'][0,:,:] 
longitudes = full_data.variables['longitude'][0,:,:]
temperature = full_data.variables['temperature'][0,:,:]
```

All three variables are 2-dimensional matrices of shape (337,451). I'm trying to do the following to get a sub-selection of the data over a specific region.

```
index = (latitudes>=44.0)&(latitudes<=45.0)&(longitudes>=-91.0)&(longitudes<=-89.0)
temp_subset = temperature[index]
lat_subset = latitudes[index]
lon_subset = longitudes[index]
```

I would expect all three of these variables to be 2-dimensional, but instead they all return a flattened array with a shape of (102,). I've tried another approach:

```
index2 = np.where((latitudes>=44.0)&(latitudes<=45.0)&(longitudes>=-91.0)&(longitudes<=-89.0))
temp = temperatures[index2[0],:]
temp2 = temp[:,index2[1]]
plt.imshow(temp2,origin='lower')
plt.colobar()
```

But my data looks quite incorrect. Is there a better way to get a 2D subset grid from a larger grid?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edub,

I suggest looking on at numpy's matrix indexing documentation, specifically http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options .  Currently, you are providing two dimensions for indexing, but no slicing information (resulting in only receiving one dimensional results). I hope this proves useful!